# Утечка памяти (GDI+)

Tags: c++, gdi+

Почему происходит утечка памяти?

```
while (true)
{
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);


    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что тут происходит утечка памяти? И какая утечка?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Pb2z9b9
если я запущу код эта шкала будет постоянно расти вверх

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович ну так а утечка памяти где? Пользуйтесь, пожалуйста, специализированными инструментами для поиска утечек памяти, а не гадайте на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Вы передаете мусор в `gdiplusStartupInput`. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Структура `gdiplusStartupInput` используется инициализированная по-умолчанию, что провоцирует создание фоновых потоков, которое потом не обрабатывается. Корректная инициализация, не порождающая утечек, выглядит вот так:

```
for(;;)
{
    ::ULONG_PTR token{};
    ::Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput input{};
    input.GdiplusVersion = 1;
    input.DebugEventCallback = nullptr;
    input.SuppressBackgroundThread = TRUE;
    input.SuppressExternalCodecs = TRUE;
    if(::Gdiplus::Status::Ok == ::Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&token, &input, nullptr))
    {
        ::Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(token);
    }
}
```